# Scraper: distinguishing meaningful text from meaningless items, hadoop

Tags: html, hadoop, mapreduce, web-scraping, nutch

I'm trying to build a crawler and scraper in Apache Nutch to find all the pages containing a section talking about a particular word-topic (e.g. "election","elections", "vote", etc).

Once I have crawled, Nutch cleans the HTML from stop words, and tags, but it doesn't take out menu voices (that are in every pages of the website).
So it could happen that when you look for all the pages talking about elections, you could retrieve a whole website because it has the word "elections" in its menu and therefore in every page.

I was wondering if techniques that analyze multiple pages of the website to understand what is the main template of a page, exist. Useful papers and/or implementations/libraries.

I was thinking about creating some kind of hadoop Job that analyzed similarities between multiple pages to extract a template. But the same website could have multiple templates, so it is hard to think of an effective way to do that.

E.G.

WEBPage 1:

```
MENU HOME VOTE ELECTION NEWS

meaningful text... elections ....
```

WebPage 2:

```
MENU HOME VOTE ELECTION NEWS

meaningful text... talking about swimming pools ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which branch of Nutch (1.x/2.x) are you using, but at the moment I can think of a couple of approaches:

Take a look at [NUTCH-585](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-585) which will be helpful if you are not crawling many different sites and if you can specify which nodes of your HTML content you want to exclude from the indexed content.

If you're working with different sites and the previous approach is not feasible take a look at [NUTCH-961](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-961) which uses the boilerplate feature inside Apache Tika to guess what texts matter from your HTML content. This library uses some algorithms and provides several extractors, you could try it and see what works for you. In my experience I've had some issues with news sites that had a lot of comments and some of the comments ended up being indexed alone with the main article content, but it was a minor issue after all. In any case this approach could work very well for a lot of cases.

Also you can take a peek at [NUTCH-1870](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1870) which let you specify XPath expressions to extract certain specific parts of the webpage as separated fields, using this with the right boost parameters in Solr could improve your precision.